# How do I move the javascript from the body element into a specific div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues with a javascript countdown I am using. I've placed the code within a certain div in my .html file, however the countdown is showing within the bottom of the body element, when I need it to show in a div inside of a certain section. I've tried everything I possibly could but I am just getting started in javascript. Any input would be great.

```
    <section id="information">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2>Countdown to our Wedding Date!</h2>
        <div id="countdown">

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ringer = {
          countdown_to: "11/24/2016",
          rings: {
            'DAYS': {
              s: 86400000, // mseconds in a day,
              max: 365
            },
            'HOURS': {
              s: 3600000, // mseconds per hour,
              max: 24
            },
            'MINUTES': {
              s: 60000, // mseconds per minute
              max: 60
            },
            'SECONDS': {
              s: 1000,
              max: 60
            },
          },
          r_count: 4,
          r_spacing: 10, // px
          r_size: 100, // px
          r_thickness: 2, // px
          update_interval: 11, // ms

          init: function(){

            $r = ringer;
            $r.cvs = document.createElement('canvas');

            $r.size = {
              w: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness) * $r.r_count + ($r.r_spacing*($r.r_count-1)),
              h: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness)
            };

            $r.cvs.setAttribute('width',$r.size.w);
            $r.cvs.setAttribute('height',$r.size.h);
            $r.ctx = $r.cvs.getContext('2d');
            $("#countdown").append($r.cvs);
            $r.cvs = $($r.cvs);
            $r.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            $r.actual_size = $r.r_size + $r.r_thickness;
            $r.countdown_to_time = new Date($r.countdown_to).getTime();
            $r.cvs.css({ width: $r.size.w+"px", height: $r.size.h+"px" });
            $r.go();
          },
          ctx: null,
          go: function(){
            var idx=0;

            $r.time = (new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time;


            for(var r_key in $r.rings) $r.unit(idx++,r_key,$r.rings[r_key]);

            setTimeout($r.go,$r.update_interval);
          },
          unit: function(idx,label,ring) {
            var x,y, value, ring_secs = ring.s;
            value = parseFloat($r.time/ring_secs);
            $r.time-=Math.round(parseInt(value)) * ring_secs;
            value = Math.abs(value);

            x = ($r.r_size*.5 + $r.r_thickness*.5);
            x +=+(idx*($r.r_size+$r.r_spacing+$r.r_thickness));
            y = $r.r_size*.5;
            y += $r.r_thickness*.5;

            // calculate arc end angle
            var degrees = 270-(value / ring.max) * 360.0;
            var endAngle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

            $r.ctx.save();

            $r.ctx.translate(x,y);
            $r.ctx.clearRect($r.actual_size*-0.5,$r.actual_size*-0.5,$r.actual_size,$r.actual_size);

            // first circle
            $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.2)";
            $r.ctx.beginPath();
            $r.ctx.arc(0,0,$r.r_size/2,0,2 * Math.PI, 2);
            $r.ctx.lineWidth =$r.r_thickness;
            $r.ctx.stroke();

            // second circle
            $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(253, 128, 1, 0.9)";
            $r.ctx.beginPath();
            $r.ctx.arc(0,0,$r.r_size/2,3*Math.PI/2,0,endAngle, 1);
            $r.ctx.lineWidth =$r.r_thickness;
            $r.ctx.stroke();

            // label
            $r.ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

            $r.ctx.font = '12px Helvetica';
            $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);
            $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 23);

            $r.ctx.font = 'bold 40px Helvetica';
            $r.ctx.fillText(Math.floor(value), 0, 10);

            $r.ctx.restore();
          }
        }

        ringer.init();
        </script>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

p.s. The javascript code is from http://codepen.io/lawrencealan/pen/cdwhm

my codepen: http://codepen.io/razahuss/pen/qZKBKQ

Comment: showing things on various parts of the display is CSS work nothing to do with where you place your JS code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change this line:**

```
$("#countdown").append($r.cvs);
```

**To this:**

```
$("#countdown").html($r.cvs);
```

Also, you should add a height value to your countdown div to make sure it doesn't collapse, replacing the opening tag with this:

```
<div id="countdown" style="height: 450px">
```

Comment: You are awesome sir.. That seemed to fix the issue. Do you mind explaining how?

Comment: I took a wild guess, and just tried to make sure that inside the countdown div there was only the canvas element, and that it had enough height to show it. Otherwise it might appear outside the div and cause all sorts of weird behaviour. Happy wedding!

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the output of this code, and it does look like the countdown is rendering within your #countdown div.  As user Redu said a few minutes ago, where this javascript is placed within your HTML won't matter - the positioning will be totally a matter of HTML and CSS.

It looks to me like you're using bootstrap.  (Do you have that required in your header?)  What other CSS are you using?  Putting all of your code in a codepen is helpful because then we can take a look at it.

It seems as if you might be new to coding, which is awesome.  This is a great project for you to use to learn.

Comment: Thank you. It's been a learning process, but has been frustrating with javascript.

Comment: You may find it easier to create a separate javascript file, rather than to include it as a script within your HTML.  (That's my personal preference, anyway.)  As Redu mentioned, it doesn't matter where the script goes in the HTML - it could be in the header or footer and it would do exactly the same thing.  For that reason, I like to keep my HTML clean and move the scripts into files that I require at the bottom of my HTML file.  What is the environment you are working in?  I may be able to make some suggestions about how to set the project up that will make your life easier.

Comment: I'm just coding with a text editor (atom) and looking at my index.html locally in the browser..

Comment: What type of environment would speed up my process as a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

can you please create a codepen or jsfiddle with your code.
Issue Seems to be with css of the div over which the countdown is plotted.

Comment: http://codepen.io/razahuss/pen/qZKBKQ
I've literally copy and pasted code from my text editor into codepen. In codepen, it shows the countdown rings within the div, but when I look at my index.html page locally, the countdown rings are not even there.
@ravi sinha

Comment: codepen is an intelligent compiler which ignore standard syntax mistakes which regular compiler doesn't ignore. Can you please make this changes and check again :
1. remove "<div class="wrapper">" before head and add it just below <body> tag.
2. remove </div> after body and bring it before body.

Comment: replicated the issue in my local and made below changes to fix the issue. the UI is looking really good :)
1. added this in <head> section
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
2. created a file called script.js under js directory and pasted all the content from codepen site to this. 
3. to call load the script, wrapped the entire js under below code:
$(document).ready(function(){
});

Comment: In addition made the changes as mentioned in the first comment i.e; adding div with class wrapper inside body tag.